# Django 1.5, Apache, wsgi.py - ImportError: Could not import settings

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, virtualenvwrapper

I have seen others post on this on StackOverflow (mainly for Django 1.4), but none of those provided a successful solution for me.

I am unable to setup Django 1.5.1 correctly with Apache. I receive the following error:

"ImportError: Could not import settings 'foobar.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named foobar.settings"

Using a fresh install of Xubuntu 13.04 on virtualbox.

Here is my setup script

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential nmap python-dev

$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper

$ cd ~
$ vim .bashrc

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/foobar.com
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
# save .bashrc

$ . .bashrc

$ mkdir -p foobar.com/prod
$ cd foobar.com/prod

# start a python project with virtualenv
$ mkvirtualenv foobar --no-site-packages
$ workon foobar

$ pip install django

# this will create project root
$ django-admin.py startproject foobar

vim foobar/foobar/settings.py
# add database settings to settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/foobar/foobar.db'
    }
}
# save settings.py

$ cd /home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar
python manage.py syncdb

# create directory for static files
$ mkdir static

# create directory for apache log files
$ cd /home/banjo/foobar.com/prod
$ mkdir logs

$ pip freeze > requirements.txt

# create apache .conf file for site
$ sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/foobar.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin banjo@foobar.com
  ServerName foobar
  ServerAlias foobar

  Alias /static/ /home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/static/

  <Directory /home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/static>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/logs/apache_error.log
  CustomLog /home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/logs/apache_access.log combined

  WSGIDaemonProcess foobar threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/foobar:/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup foobar

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/foobar/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
# save .conf file

# add site to /etc/hosts
$ vim /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 foobar
# save hosts file


# configure .wsgi file and the following
$ vim /home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/foobar/wsgi.py

import sys

path = '/home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/foobar'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, '/home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/foobar')

# save wsgi.py

$ sudo a2ensite foobar.conf
$ sudo service apache2 restart

# open browser and navigate to site
http://foobar
```

Here is my directory tree

```
+-- foobar.com
¦   +-- prod
¦       +-- foobar
¦       ¦   +-- foobar
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- foobar.db
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- __init__.py
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- __init__.pyc
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- settings.py
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- settings.pyc
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- urls.py
¦       ¦   ¦   +-- wsgi.py
¦       ¦   +-- manage.py
¦       ¦   +-- static
¦       +-- logs
¦       ¦   +-- apache_access.log
¦       ¦   +-- apache_error.log
¦       +-- requirements.txt
```

Here is the full error log

```
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=3424): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/banjo/foobar.com/prod/foobar/foobar/wsgi.py'.
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in call
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/init.py", line 53, in getattr
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._setup(name)
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/init.py", line 48, in _setup
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/init.py", line 134, in init
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Tue May 21 14:02:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: Could not import settings 'foobar.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named foobar.settings
```

Here is the output of my sys path

```
(foobar)banjo@sandbox:~/foobar.com$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:32:33) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path: print path
... 

/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Up for all the install commands !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your python path, making the appropriate path substitution.

```
/unix/path/above/foobar/foobar.com/prod/foobar/
```

One way add to your path is to create a file called foobar.pth (or whatever.pth) and place it in the following directory:

```
/home/banjo/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

That file should contain a newline separated list of paths that you want to add to your virtual environment.

```
/unix/path/above/foobar/foobar.com/prod/foobar/
```

**Update**: actually this might be the path entry to make:

```
/unix/path/above/foobar/foobar.com/prod/foobar/foobar/
```

Adding the path here has the added benefit of exposing this path to the Python interpreter and not just through the wsgi.py script.

Comment: Thank you Joe J! I created the .pth file as you suggested. At first I added the path you included in your update (which is the directory containing settings.py and wsgi.py) but that did not work. Next I tried one directory up (the one containing manage.py) and it worked!!

Comment: Sorry, this was a total newb mistake. It turns out the .pth file is not needed. My mistake was setting the sys.path wrong in my wsgi.py file. Originally, I set the path to the directory which contains settings.py. The correct setting is to set the path to the project directory (the one containing manage.py). This is the same path that I had added to the .pth file, but now instead only used in wsgi.py.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on 26th july 2013 (in addition I was utilizing virtualenv as well)

I solved this by referring to:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/